# What is the easiest way to make my Macbook Pro's webcam externally accessible?

Tags: macbook, webcam

I want to set it up on my coffee table and monitor my dogs during the day....

Whats the easiest to set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set this up using www.justin.tv